# Big O N^2 (Log N)

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

I am a complete newbie at Big O and I am a bit stumped by this. 
I have:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n*n; i *= 2)
```

In my mind this would equate to [image: N^2 * Log N]

Am I right or can it be simplified to N as you are doubling the inputs with `n*n` and halving it with `i *= 2`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you have

```
O(log2(n ^ 2))
```

which is

```
O(2 * log2(n))
```

or just

```
O(ln N)
```

note if `n * n > (1 << 30)` you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. So I was wrong, thanks for the help. So that would just equate to O(2Log2(n)). But how does that work? I thought if you double the input space it becomes N^2 and if you halve the amount of iterations it becomes Log2N, so do they not multiply together? I have been trying to find every example I can and finding the patterns but this is a new one to me

Comment: @Matt The bit-O doesn't consider the factor involved. This means that double, or half O(n) is O(n). This is why O(logBase10(N)) is the same as O(ln N);

Comment: All right. Makes sense. Thanks for all your help @Peter.